# What to do about content of iframe sometimes not loading?

Tags: javascript, iframe, d3.js, nvd3.js, reveal.js

I don't really know where to ask this question because I'm not sure what the problem really is.

I'm using NVD3 and datamaps to visualize data and then I embed these visualizations in a reveal.js presentation by using iframes.

[Here is the link to the presentation that includes some of my visualization](http://ourworldindata.org/roser/presentation/June2014OnlinePresentation/June2014OnlinePresentation.html).

The problem now is that sometimes the visualiation in the iframe is not loaded completely and the iframe only includes a few random elements and the data visualization is not shown.

This happens with both types of visualizations, datamaps and NVD3: [Here is a screenshot of the NVD3 not loading](http://ourworldindata.org/roser/presentation/June2014OnlinePresentation/issue/ScreenshotNotLoadingNVD3.png) and [here of the datamaps not loading](http://ourworldindata.org/roser/presentation/June2014OnlinePresentation/issue/ScreenshotNotLoadingDatamaps.png). (Mostly the iframe is loading when you refresh but this is not very elegant really.)

How do I find out what causes this problem? And is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Check the browser console for any possible errors, or use the Net Tab of the developer tools or Firebug.

Comment: All of the visualisations work if I load them 1 by 1 – something with loading them all at once causes this problem.. But it was a good idea to check the console: There is 1 error that comes up repeatedly: TypeError: d3_window.getComputedStyle(...) is null   ...(n < 2) return d3_window.getComputedStyle(this.node(), null).getPropertyValue(na...